# Common Lisp lexer generator that allows state variables

Tags: parsing, common-lisp, yacc, lex, sbcl

Neither of the two main lexer generators commonly referenced, cl-lex and lispbuilder-lexer allow for state variables in the "action blocks", making it impossible to recognize a c-style multi-line comment, for example.

What is a lexer generator in Common Lisp that can recognize a c-style multi-line comment as a token?

Correction: This lexer actually needs to recognize nested, balanced multiline comments (not exactly C-style). So I can't do away with state-variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recognize a C-style multiline comment with the following regular expression:

```
[/][*][^*]*[*]+([^*/][^*]*[*]+)*[/]
```

It should work with any library which uses Posix-compatible extended regex syntax; although a bit hard to read because `*` is extensively used both as an operator and as a literal character, it uses no non-regular features. It does rely on inverted character classes (`[^*]`, for example) matching the newline character, but afaik that is pretty well universal, even for regex engines in which a wildcard does not match newline.

Comment: actually, in my case I need to recognize balanced, nested multiline coments. so I do think I need a comment-level state variable

Comment: @erjoalgo: Yes, those wouldn't be C-style, and they are not recognizable with a regular expression. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I was aware that this is possible but in my experience this (allowing repetitions on groups as opposed to only simple character classes) seems to be rarely supported? I could be wrong.

Comment: @erjoalgo: It's certainly available in every standard regex library, and in all the lexical generators I'm familiar with. I'm not familiar with the ones you mentioned, but I checked their docs: The `lispbuilder-lexer` brief documentation includes, for example, `"[0-9]+([.][0-9]+([Ee][0-9]+)?)"` (which is an optional group, not a repeated group, but the principle is roughly the same), and the library `cl-lex` uses claims to be mostly Perl-compatible, so it would be highly surprising if it didn't allow repeated groups.

Comment: yes, I'm aware it is available in most lexical generators. I think it is another shortcomming of those two cl-lexers, that they do not seem to natively allow building on named subtokens

Comment: @erjoalgo cl-lex *does* support all the regular expressions mentioned above

Comment: does it support naming a regular expression and building on it? it's probably not too difficult to get around this, but I don't think it is supported natively

Comment: @erjoalgo: regex macros are a feature of lex and its various derivates (flex, jflex, ocamllex, and probably many others), but they are *macros* and consequently recursive expansion is not going to work. They add nothing aside from readability to regex specifications (and there is a tendency to overuse them, removing even that advantage). Allowing recursive matching would make the "regex" into a CFG. This feature is allowed in ANTLR4, at least, but it is uncommon because it cannot make use of the highly efficient regular expression matching algorithm.

Comment: @erjoalgo: The macro nature of named subexpressions is shown clearly in the PLY implementation, which is based on simple string concatenation. [documentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn14). Looks to me like you could easily build this into cl-lex since it allows regexes to be supplied as sexprs.

Comment: @erjoalgo cl-lex allows named groups and this is mentioned in the doc strings in the code.

Comment: @qudit: If you're talking about [this feature](http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/#*allow-named-registers*), I think that's a different concept. At least, it's different from the concept I was talking about; I don't really know what erjoalgo is looking for.

Comment: @rici Yes, that's what I'm talking about.  cl-lex does not support the macros you're taking about.  I mentioned it because ejoalgo seemed to be saying that it did not support named groups or even repetition.  This is not true.

Comment: It's a nice feature of cl-lex to be able to capture groups within the regexp, although I was referring to the macro nature of named subexpressions. But even this is ultimately just a convenience, I would be able to get around it easily. My problem is that I do need state, I was able to get around this by hacking something into lispbuilder-lexer but I guess I was looking for a lexer closer to flex in CL